# Ext is not defined IN Firefox?

Tags: extjs

I have a question about Ext JS (error message).

**Explanation**

I had code that was running fine in all browsers but yesterday at noon I tried to 
modify de css and I think I messed something up.

After saving my document and uploading it to my server, I encountered the error:
 `Ext is not defined` and `illegal character`. I really have no clue where this error comes from. It makes my whole system crash in Firefox. The weird thing is that IE has no problem at all and reads everything as it should.

At first, I was thinking of a catch (browsers problem) but it isn't that.

Look at the images below for error messages and code.

**Code**

I have an asp include at the top of every page, which includes all of the available .js's.

Here is the image of the errors:

[image: firebug error messages]

Answer (score 0):

"Ext is not defined" means you have some error that is preventing Ext from being loaded properly, then nothing after that will work.  According to your screenshot you have an illegal character in "ext-jq...pter.js" -- what is that, some custom build?  If you resolve that error, the "Ext is not defined" errors will probably go away.

Comment: what would make it work in IE and not in FF ?
if that is the problem i'm looking in to that 
at the moment !

Comment: Caching?  It would be very unusual if IE is actually working while there is an error like that.  Try Ctrl-R and see if it still works.

Comment: i just tryed ctr-R and still works fin 

if i look a the end of my file that has "illegal character"
this is what you see 

d.createInterceptor;window.detachEvent("onunload",a)}window.attachEvent("onunload",a)}})();��������������������

im still realy have no clue

Comment: well all of those funky characters are the end probably shouldn't be there. did you try removing those ?  There might be something on your upload process that didn't work.

also, did you check the Net tab with firebug to make sure that all your javascript includes loads ?

Comment: ok i found a solution that look weird but worked... 
i uploaded andchange my ext-jquery-adapter.asp with the debug on then
i but the original back and BAM it work 

did the same with de etx-base.js   and not javascript error...
for what i can see this was a case of coruption from changin a css and by what a read ext-js look and build there file from the css file and images where missing ...   it could be a solution i dunno 

have fun thanx averyone again